# Is it possible to pass a blob file as an object via an api call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, base64, blob

I'm not sure if the above is possible or not. But I simply want to pass a blob file or its base64 representation inside an object, so on the server side I can send it to the database or even send it as a pdf via email. I have most of the logic down... I'm just struggling with sending the file over from client to the server using the api call. Would anyone know how to do this in angularjs?

I see this alot:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(event){
       createImage(event.target.result); //event.target.results contains the base64 code to create the image.
        };
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);//Convert the blob from clipboard to base64
```

But because its an asynchronous method I can't assign it my object variable right away... So i tried to assign to a local variable on the onload after logging it to the console, however it was still returning undefined. I don't know if this is the right way to approach this but any help would be grateful.

If you need any more info let me know.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To send a Blob from an AngularJS client to a server, use the [$http Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

```
var config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined } });

$http.post(url, blob, config);
```

It is important that the content type be set to `undefined` to override the AngularJS default of `application/json`.